# Converting file to PCM using SoX

Tags: command-line, audio, sox, audio-conversion

I am using SoX.

> A-Law, 8000 Hz, 64 Kbps, mono

Is the format I need

What I tried:

> input -c 1 -r 8000 output

It is not working for me, please advise.

I get the file output, it's just not the right format.

Answer (score -1):

```
input -c 1 -r 8000 -e a-law output
```

about 64 Kbps, now search command

Comment: Welcome Alli Storm. Please expand your answer explaining what the options do, it should be useful for a more wide audience.